# Prove there is a sequence to satisfy the following

Tags: general-topology

Let set $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. I want to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a sequence  {($a_k$,$b_k$)}$_{k=1}^\infty$ of open intervals that satisfy

$A\subseteq$$\cup$$_{k=1}^\infty$($a_k$,$b_k$)   and    $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$($b_k$$-$$a_k$)<$\varepsilon$

Any ideas would be welcome , thank you .

Comment: I guess you can enumerate $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ as $q_i$ and have small intervals $(q_i- \epsilon/2^i, q_i + \epsilon /2^i)$.

Comment: @Brian Ding Really helpful . Only think I had to change is $(q_i- \epsilon/2^i, q_i + \epsilon /2^i)$ to $(q_i- \epsilon/4^i, q_i + \epsilon /4^i)$ so it sums up to 2/3$\epsilon$

Comment: As small as you want =v =